# Регулярные выражения java поиск в многострочной строке

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Хочу найти в строке гиперссылку[image]
написал для этого регулярное выражение, но оно отказывается работать

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("Действующие вещества:.*[^c]class\"\">(.*)[^<]</a>");
matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        while(matcher.find()){
            dop1.put("Действующие вещества", matcher.group(1));
        }
```

Постоянно возвращает null;
Что не так?
Строка, в которой ищу
s = "Действующие вещества:\n" +
                "                                    *";

Comment: Строку текстом в вопрос добавь.

Comment: Может, `"(?s)Действующие вещества:.*?class=\"\">(.*?)</a>"`?

Comment: Строку добавил, вариант Виктора не подошел

Comment: [Моя регулярка очень даже подходит](https://ideone.com/jprnM7)

Comment: спасибо большое, а почему без знака вопроса не работало? он же получается, говорит о том, что такого символа может и не быть?

Comment: Все "знаки вопроса" тут необходимы, какой именно вам непонятен?

Comment: Второй знак вопроса, который входит в группу, которую я забираю делает поиск не жадным, это как я понял, а первый знак вопроса проверяет на всякий случай нет ли пробела?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
String regex = "(?s)Действующие вещества:.*?class=\"\">(.*?)</a>";
```

**Подробности**

- `(?s)` - модификатор, разрешающий точке находить символы перевода строки (= `Pattern.DOTALL`)
- `Действующие вещества:` - строка `Действующие вещества:`
- `.*?` - 0 и более любых символов, как можно меньше (так как квантификатор `*?` нежадный, "ленивый")
- `class="">` - строка `class="">`
- `(.*?)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1 (`matcher.group(1)`): 0 и более любых символов, как можно меньше
- `</a>` - строка `</a>`

[Пример использования](https://ideone.com/jprnM7):

```
String s = "Действующие вещества:</td>\n" +
            "                                    <td><a href=\"\" class=\"\">*</a></td>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)Действующие вещества:.*?class=\"\">(.*?)</a>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Действующие вещества: "+ matcher.group(1));
}
// => Действующие вещества: *
```